# How do I access sys.certificates table in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, certificate, azure-sql-database

I tried to query all items from `sys.certificates` table in SQL Azure - both from the master database and from the usual databases - every time it yields

> Invalid object name 'sys.certificates'

error message. The same query works fine on local SQL Express.

Is this table not accessible in SQL Azure? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336238.aspx) answers your question, did you review it?

Comment: @Pondlife:I did search, but didn't find that thing.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates and encryption in general are not supported in SQL Azure

Check these out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336253.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394115.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its not supported in Azure SQL

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336238.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a more in depth explanation about which kinds of encryption are and are not supported by SQL Azure on TechNet:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh351833.aspx

> SQL Azure does not currently support the standard
>   data-encryption mechanisms that SQL Server supports. These include
>   transparent data encryption, asymmetric keys, symmetric keys, and
>   Transact-SQL functions such as ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE and
>   DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE, CREATE/ALTER/DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY or
>   CREATE/ALTER/DROP MASTER KEY.